# select all data on type , and change select if a row exists

Tags: mysql, sql

am new here so please redirect me if am posting this wrong
sorry i can't post images yet

[image: image1]

I have this table , I want to select all where type = 'Maladie'
but ... if a row with type = 'Reprise' that contains a date between any of the maladie type ones then i must show 
**maladie row date start -> Reprise rows date start**
instead of
**maladie row date start -> maladie row date end**

so result for that image would look like this

[image: image2]

note: rows with type Reprise may or may not exist

thnks

Comment: Does a reprise always only cover a single day? Can two reprise records match a main table record? What to do then?

Comment: yes , it must be one day
this is a table of diseases holidays, u can always get better and return to work before ur diseases holiday ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer join the reprise records. Where you find a match use its dates, where you don't use the original dates:

```
select
  m.mat,
  m.start,
  coalesce(r.end, m.end) as end,
  m.number_days,
  m.number_hours
from (select * from mytable where type = 'Maladie') m
left join (select * from mytable where type = 'Reprise') r 
              on r.mat = m.mat and r.start between m.start and m.end;
```

If there can be more than one reprise record per maladie date range and you want to take the first one then, use:

```
select
  m.mat,
  m.start,
  coalesce(r.repday, m.end) as end,
  m.number_days,
  m.number_hours
from (select * from mytable where type = 'Maladie') m
left join 
(
  select mat, min(end) as repday
  from mytable 
  where type = 'Reprise' 
  group by mat
) r on r.mat = m.mat and r.repday between m.start and m.end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create self join and filter type that use min to catch first date if there is more that one reprise

```
SELECT a.mat
    ,a.start
    ,min(coalesce(b.END, a.END)) AS END
    ,a.number_of_days
    ,a.number_of_hours
    ,type
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT mat
        ,start AS start
        ,END AS END
    FROM table1 t
    WHERE t.type = 'Reprise'

    ) b ON b.start BETWEEN a.start
        AND a.END and a.mat=b.mat
WHERE type = 'Malaide'
GROUP BY a.mat
,a.start
ORDER BY start
```

Comment: According to standard SQL this is invalid. In the derived query you group by mat and get one of its starts and one of its ends (as you don't say which by using aggregate functions such as MIN or MAX). You can end up with a start from one record and an end from another, though this is not very likely. Even if it is data from only one record you take you suppress the others arbitrarily, when there is more than one reprise record per mat..